# Evernote getResource issue

Tags: python, integration, evernote

I have question regarding Evernote API.
Currently I'm using latest version of Evernote SDK for Python (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python),
but I'm not able to fetch all data from my note.

For example, I have note with text and image, but getResource returns only image from this note.

Is there any other way to fetch note content ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get note content, you need to call [getNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote). [Resource](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Resource) represents a file attached to the note. You can learn more of the data structure [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/data_structure.php).